# Cannot ls ~/.Trash in the Terminal in Catalina (operation not permitted)

Tags: terminal, permission, catalina, trash

Ever since buying a new Mac, which has forced me to upgrade to Catalina, I cannot view the Trash folder in the Terminal. `ls ~/.Trash` just gives `ls: .Trash: Operation not permitted`. So does `sudo ls ~/.Trash`. According to `ls -al ~`, the permissions for `~/.Trash` are `drwx------`, and the owner is me. `sudo chmod a+x ~/.Trash` and `sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash` both fail with the same error.

Is it possible to view the Trash in the terminal in Catalina?

Comment: Check this article: [Fix Terminal “Operation not permitted” Error in MacOS Mojave](http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/).

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You have to give the Terminal.app Full Disk permissions in the security settings.

[image]

Comment: Interesting! While this may seem like a giant hassle, it's clear to me that this decision could also potentially block a whole lot of malware. I think I actually support this design decision on Apple's part.

Comment: This answer helps a lot, thanks. But it also leaves new questions: a. What's the mechanism whereby some files/folders are made special this way? It's not just `~/.Trash`, many subfolders of `~/Library/Caches` for instance are also "untouchable". As not even the superuser can see them, it's clearly no traditional Unix mechanism; it is also not one of the file "flags" as `ls -ldO ~/.Trash` shows. And b. How can we see which files/folders are this kind, from the Unix side or otherwise? Other than trial and error, I mean.

Comment: And What Do You Know: even after this, some folders are *still* untouchable! Example here: https://gist.github.com/nobrowser/787f64a628c32d0e98379a0771bdf764

Comment: I believe you are referring to `chflags`, which can be modified by using the chflags command. I would recommend reading the man page. I would also like to caution against changing chflags for system files as it can cause issues.

Comment: @virus.cmd perhaps, but I wasn't necessarily thinking about *changing* them, in fact they are apropos to the main issue here. Which is kind of the whole point of my comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through many solutions and this one is the best. Let me tell you that this also does not help to delete the files but makes life easy.

By giving the 'Full Disk Access' to terminal you can actually go inside with 'cd' and see the content and even by giving '777' permission to all the content there you can move everything outside '.Trash' in some other folder and keep the stuff parked there. This will get away the annoying 'Files are in use' warning and you can use empty your trash bin normally.

This is a great solution, if you do not mind one unnecessary folder of 0 size lying in your disk.